# MySQL insert into partition 'p'

Tags: mysql, partitioning, load-data-infile

This question has three layers, depending on where my idea(s) is incorrect or not feasible:

1. I have CSV files of tickers: A.csv, AAPL.csv...,etc -2000 stocks in total- containing columns DATE,SYMBOL,OPEN,HI,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME

I want to CREATE TABLE STOCKS (id,date,symbol,...) HASH PARTITION by id (auto-incremented), and create 663 partitions.
OR CREATE TABLE STOCKS (date,symbol,...) HASH PARTITION BY date, 663 partitions.

Which option should I choose? [PS: 663 partitions because stockdata is for 13 years * 51 weeks per year]

2. Is there a way to select a particular hash partition to insert rows into?
   As in: For table 'stocks', HASH partitioned on 'id' column (664 partitions) can something like the following be done:
   INSERT into partition p52 VALUES(...)
3. If 2 is possible, can the same be done for LOAD DATA IN FILE A.csv such that
   . rows 1-2000 go to partition p0
   . rows 2001-4000 go to partition p1...
   . and so on.

[I am assuming Inserts will be faster if I specify which partition I want to insert into. Insert statements I tried in the past on a partitioned table directly as INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(..) was very slow compared to an unpartitioned stocks table.]

Comment: Why do you want to partition the data?

Comment: Just some context: [Using MySQL Innodb engine] 1 stock: 13 years * 262 weekdays * 390 data-points per day = 1,328,340 rows. For our purpose, at least 2000 stocks: 1,328,340*2000 = 2,656,680,000 rows. Plus everyday 2000 stocks * 390 data-points = 780,000 additional rows will be inserted post working hours EVERY working day henceforth once the db is in place.

Comment: Currently I am testing this whole setup with just 100 stocks CSV files. I'm testing on my local machine MySQL how to architecture the stocks db for (ideally uniform) insert speeds, querying speed, before I setup the final schema plan on a cloud db.

Comment: You've not answered my question, but RJ is the expert, so just do what he says

Comment: Just adding to simplify my rant, I'm partitioning keeping the table size in mind which will be growing by 780,000 rows everyday. Once when I had tested my 100 stocks setup on a different schema plan for 100 iterations I had run out of memory

Comment: Will do, thank you!

Comment: You appear to be making assumptions about the benefits of partitioning which are simply untrue.

Comment: Ok I'll try what RJ has recommended then. Thanks

Comment: Will you be adding new data every day?  You really should not reload all the data every day; if you are, there are different techniques we need to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Hash partitioning; it is either of no benefit (when doing point queries) or terribly inefficient (when doing range queries).

If date+symbol is `UNIQUE`, then get rid of `id`; it is an unnecessary burden.  Assuming that, then use

```
PRIMARY KEY(symbol, date),
INDEX(date)
```

The secondary index is optional -- include it only if you do need to search by `date` without specifying a `symbol`.

Consider normalizing `symbol` to `symbol_id`, where it is `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` so that only 2 bytes is used for the symbol.

Why are you concerned about `INSERT` speed?  That is a one-time task, no?

Your math sounds like a rather small table -- 13*51*2000 = 1.3M rows -- perhaps 100-200MB.

PS.  Which of the 52 weeks are you leaving off?

**Updates**

If you are adding more rows every day, the loads will much smaller and need different techniques.  In particular, you may have a single file with the day's closing prices, not 2000 files?

If the data is actually more than 100GB, and you are starting with 13 years' worth of data, I recommend the following:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(date))
```

and start with the following partitions (even before doing the LOADs):

- An empty partition (LESS THAN the oldest date)
- One huge partition with all data before the last month of your dataset.
- One month partition (continuing end of the initial load, plus the rest of the month)
- An empty "future" partition.

Every night check to see if it is time to add a new month, in which case, `ALTER TABLE REPARTITION future` into the next month and a new (empty) 'future'.

More details:   http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

The reason for this odd partition setup:  each night when you load new data, it will hit 2000 different spots in the current "month" partition; this will probably fit in cache, thereby avoiding thrashing.

And each `LOAD DATA` of the initial load will load a lot of data at one spot in the huge partition, again being efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure where am I making a mistake in my explanation, but the total size of all 100 CSV's is around 5GB as of now. For 2000 files, I will have in 100's of GB size

Comment: also not exactly weeks, but weekends are being left off.

Comment: @AkankshaJollySharma - What I was fishing for is whether the data refers to daily data or hourly data or maybe even every trade.  Meanwhile, my recommendations stand in spite of the table being 1000 times as big as I originally thought.  Please add those size numbers to the original Question.  Also any other info, such as the likely `SELECTs`.

Comment: @AkankshaJollySharma - See the additions I made to my Answer.  (I first encountered this task 18 years ago; I have had a long time to think about it.)